# Centrifugal force, Newton's third law and increasing radius?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

Say there are two masses $m$ and $M$ that are independent. They are travelling in a circular path around the same centre with the same angular velocity. For mass $M$, centrifugal force is larger and the centripetal force is also larger as well (centripetal acceleration is constant) than for mass $m$. From a rotating reference frame, the centripetal and centrifugal force is opposite and equal. It is said that $M$ is circling at a larger radius than $m$ because of this greater centrifugal force. But centrifugal force is equal to centripetal force so why does the radius change?

Maybe my question is better phrased as "why does increasing centrifugal force result in increased radius?"

I have looked at similar questions but they tend to be discussions on the reality of centrifugal force which Im aware is only inertial and exists only for the sake of accelerating reference frames. Please do not delete this. this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Are they moving around the same circle?

Comment: Are the two particles independent or do they interact and the interaction is at the origin of the circular motion?

Comment: do not interact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing centrifugal force, on its own, does not "result" in an increased radius.  There is an interplay between the fictitious force, radius, and speed.

The question is missing several details which would be needed to answer the question.  My *guess* is that the intent is that the masses are rotating *at the same angular velocity*.  If this is true, then we can use the equation for [centrifugal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force), $F=m\omega^2r$, where $\omega$ is the angular velocity.  It's easy to see that if $m$ is constant and $\omega$ is constant, and we increase r, the force must increase.  We write this $F\propto r$.  The force is *proportional* to the radius.

But that's just one setup.  It could also be that the two masses are rotating and have *the same linear speed*.  They may both be moving at 5 meters per second as they rotate.  Because angular speed is equal to the linear speed divided by the radius, $\omega = \frac{v}{r}$, we can plug this in to the above equation to get $F=m\frac{v^2}{r^2}r=m\frac{v^2}r$, which is another valid way to represent the same forces.  In this viewpoint, if v is constant and F goes up, r must go down.  $F\propto \frac1 r$.

How can this be?  Well, it's a different setup.  In the first setup, we kept angular speed constant while varying the radius.  In the second, we kept the linear speed constant while varying the radius.  One construction yields the results you mention, "increasing centrifugal force result in increased radius."  The second one has the exact opposite.

So you may be having trouble figuring out the universal reason why increasing centrifugal force increases radius.  The reason you're having trouble is that it isn't always true.  In some problems, the problem is set up so that it is increasing.  In other problems, it's decreasing.  You have to look at the specific problem, and figure out which constraints to apply in the math.

> It is said that M is circling at a larger radius than m because of this greater centrifugal force.

This statement is untrue in general, and the problem is ill formed.  *However*, if the problem contained additional information which you did not include in the question, then its possible that it is true.  If the problem was set up such that m and M's *linear* velocities are the same *and* the centrifugal forces experienced by both masses are the same, then the "because" in your question indeed has an answer.  The larger mass must rotate slower (angular velocity) to have the same force, and angular velocity goes down if you increase radius while keeping the linear velocity constant. But you would need that additional information to make the logic hold true.

Comment: It should be noted that the centrifugal force doesn't depend on the motion of the masses; it only depends on the motion of the reference frame. This point is ambiguous in this answer.

Comment: @BioPhysicist That is true.  It's easy for this to be ambiguous because we typically select a reference frame that is based on the motion of the masses, which makes those two motions the same.  That makes the calculations easier.  But they don't have to be the same.  The angular rate of the reference frame and the radial position of the object matter.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I only mention it since the question seems to be dependent on changing speeds/radii, which makes it confusing as to what is actually being asked about the centrifugal force. Is the OP picking a reference frame and sticking to it, or are they wanting the frame to change with the change in motion of the mass?

Comment: @BioPhysicist I instinctively assumed they were changing the frame, just because the statements given in the problem are strange, and point in that direction.  But my intuition may have gotten in the way, leading me to skip a few steps.

Comment: @CortAmmon from the text of the question, there is no doubt on the system of reference. It is unique and corresponds to the frame centered at the center of mass and co-rotating with the two masses.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by summarizing a few facts about the underlying two-body problem.

If we have two masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ (I am slightly changing the notation) in an inertial reference frame, at positions  ${\bf r}_1$ and ${\bf r}_2$, interacting with an attractive force $\bf F$ depending on the distance between the two masses, we know that we get a simplification of the problem by using as new coordinates the center of mass.
$$
{\bf R} = \frac{m_1}{M}{\bf r}_1 + \frac{m_2}{M}{\bf r}_2,
$$
where $M=m_1+m_2$,
and the relative position
$$
{\bf r}={\bf r}_2-{\bf r}_1.
$$
The motion of the center of mass is trivial, and the integration of the equations of motion for the relative position provides the function ${\bf r}(t)$. At this point, we can go back to the original coordinates to find
$$
\begin{align}
\tag{1.1}{\bf r}_1&={\bf R}-\frac{m_2}{M}{\bf r}\\
\tag{1.2}{\bf r}_2&={\bf R}-\frac{m_1}{M}{\bf r}.
\end{align}
$$
These two equations tell us that in the inertial reference frame of the center of mass (${\bf R}(t)=0$), positions ${\bf r}_1$, ${\bf r}_2$, and the origin remain always aligned and the motion of the mass $1$ is connected to the motion of mass $2$ by a central inversion and a rescaling of the distance from the origin (the common center of mass) by a factor $\frac{m_2}{m_1}$.

For every attractive central force and starting distance between the two masses, there is a starting velocity such that the resulting relative motion is a uniform circular motion. This implies that both ${\bf r}_1(t)$, ${\bf r}_2(t)$ correspond to uniform circular motions at the same angular frequency $\omega$. The distances from the common center are inversely proportional to their masses. In the limit of $m_1 \rightarrow \infty$, Eqs. $1.1$ and $1.2$ tell us that ${\bf r}_1=0$ and ${\bf r}_2={\bf r}$. In the general case, the lighter mass rotates farther from the origin than the heavier mass.

This long recap of the two-body problem in an inertial system makes it easier to discuss the problem in the non-inertial frame, centered at the center of mass position and co-rotating with the two masses. Here, each mass is at rest. The reason being the presence of an inertial centrifugal force, in addition to the common centripetal attraction. Thus, the inverse proportionality between mass and distance can be related to the resulting condition of
$$
m_i \omega^2 r_i = constant.
$$

Comment: I'm am not sure if the OP if asking about two masses attracted to each other. It looks like they are just asking about two masses moving around a circular path.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the increasing centrifugal force that "causes" the new radius, so to say. Rather, it is the increasing mass.

A larger mass requires a larger force to achieve the needed centripetal acceleration. Meaning, larger mass causes larger centripetal force, corresponding to a larger centrifugal force in the rotating frame.

- If the path, the radius, is locked (such as in a game of tetherball) then the force must increase to match this. The new larger centripetal acceleration must be achieved.
- If the path can adjust, such as for bodies in orbit, then the force might increase, just a bit less than in the other scenario, *while* the radius also increases.

We thus have the two effects simultaneously - increasing force and increasing radius - not as a result of each other but as a result of increasing mass.